# Fortify marks try-with-resources as Medium severity Issue

Tags: java, fortify

I have generated fortify code review and I got medium severity for closing FileStream(in try-with-resources block) and file.delete in finally. How do I remove these issues?

```
Category    Detail  Location    Severity
Poor Error Handling : Throw Inside Finally  FinallyBlock classA.java:108    Medium
Poor Error Handling : Throw Inside Finally  FinallyBlock    classB.java:87  Medium
```

ClassA.java: 108

```
try (OutputStream recordsFileOut = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile.toFile());
     OutputStream rejectedFileOut = new FileOutputStream(rejectedRecordsFile.toFile())) {


      ......


}
```

classB.java: 87

```
try {

} catch(IOException ex) {


} finally {
    outputFile.toFile().delete();
}
```

Comment: can you share the code that caused this warning?

Comment: Updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you are showing I can only deduce that `outputFile.toFile()` must throw some catchable exception. This will then cause `.delete()` to be bypassed and that must be something Fortify is complaing about.

See [this page](https://vulncat.hpefod.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.java.poor_error_handling_throw_inside_finally) for more details.

Comment: for classB.java: 87 I know the issue and I fixed it.

Comment: for ClassA.java: 108 I think outputstream.close can throw exception but that would mean that I have to stay away from try-with-resources completely in order to handle that.